# Date object javascript

Tags: javascript, date

var date = new Date();//Mon Mar 15 2010 12:40:05 GMT+0300 (MSK) 
    var omg = date.getDate() + 19;// 34 
    date.setDate(omg);
    document.write(date.toLocaleString()); //Sat 03 Apr 2010 12:43:00 PM MSK

How do I echo the values 3 (ie: day of month), 4 (April) and the current year?

```
alert(day); // Need 3
alert(month); // Need 4
```

Thank you

Comment: Please refer to [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Year: `date.getFullYear()`. Month: `date.getMonth()`. Date: `date.getDate()`.

Take a look at the [reference at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date).

Answer (score 2):

```
date.getDate();

date.getMonth() + 1

date.getFullYear()
```

If you want to get the date according to universal time then

```
date.getUTCDate();

date.getUTCMonth() + 1

date.getUTCFullYear()
```